# Every time I try to install a new version of R, the older version is installed. What should I do?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I previously installed the 3.6.3 version of R on my ubuntu, now I remove that version and try to reinstall the R, But the previous version is installed again.

I try by this command:

```
sudo apt install r-base
```

How can I install the new version?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Which repository are you using?

Comment: CRAN, I install through the link below https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/